# Rails locations: API Wrappers (Vaccum)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, api, model-view-controller, wrapper

In Rails -

Where should I locate an API wrapper? Under `models`?

I put the `vaccum` wrapper there but I'm getting a `NoMethodError` in the Controller. How do I make sure it is working well?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the `vacuum` wrapper? You either put that in the Model layer or create a separate service layer for it, eg. You create a service folder and make it available there. However, for simplicity I would start with creating a Model.

The `NoMethodError` from your controller is caused because Rails cannot find the method you are sending. Can you perhaps post the controller code?